# Why am I getting response code 400 in this Kotlin Volley Request?

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

I am trying to get FINRA bond data using Kotlin. I reformatted Python code that works in making the request. However, for the Kotlin Volley Request, I keep getting error code 400, and I am not sure why. I tried using a `StringRequest` although I think I need a `JsonObjectRequest.` I tried passing in formatted `json` as well as setting the `headers` and `params` with `getHeaders()` and `getParams()`. I am stuck. What am I missing? Please note, to get the json data I first need to set the `xsfr token` as the `cfruid` cookie, which is why there are two requests. I am setting the cfruid cookie correctly.

My code:

```
  private fun finraGetBondInfo(companyName: String) {
        val url = "https://www.finra.org/finra-data/fixed-income/corp-and-agency"

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireActivity())
        var cfruid = ""

        val stringRequest = object: StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            { response ->
                Log.d("Response", response)
            },
            { error ->
                Log.e("Error", error.toString())
            })
        {
            override fun  parseNetworkResponse(response : NetworkResponse) : Response<String> {
                Log.i("response", response.headers.toString());
                val cookies = HttpCookie.parse(response.headers?.get("Set-Cookie"))
                Log.d("Cookies:", cookies[0].toString())
                val indexOfEqualSign = cookies[0].toString().indexOf('=')
                cfruid = cookies[0].toString().substring(indexOfEqualSign + 1)
                Log.d("Cfruid:", cfruid)


                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response)
            }
        }

        queue.add(stringRequest)


        // Create our JSON Object for the finra call
        val json = JSONObject()
        val fieldsArray = JSONArray()
        fieldsArray.put("issueSymbolIdentifier")
        fieldsArray.put("issuerName")
        fieldsArray.put("isCallable")
        fieldsArray.put("productSubTypeCode")
        fieldsArray.put("couponRate")
        fieldsArray.put("maturityDate")
        fieldsArray.put("industryGroup")
        fieldsArray.put("moodysRating")
        fieldsArray.put("standardAndPoorsRating")
        fieldsArray.put("lastSalePrice")
        fieldsArray.put("lastSaleYield")
        json.put("fields", fieldsArray)

        json.put("dateRangeFilters", JSONArray())
        json.put("domainFilters", JSONArray())
        json.put("compareFilters", JSONArray())

        val multiJson = JSONObject()
        multiJson.put("fuzzy", false)
        multiJson.put("searchValue", companyName)
        multiJson.put("synonym", true)
        val subfieldsJson = JSONObject()
        subfieldsJson.put("name", "issuerName")
        subfieldsJson.put("boost", 1)
        multiJson.put("fields", subfieldsJson)
        val multiArray = JSONArray()
        multiArray.put(multiJson)

        json.put("multiFieldMatchFilters", multiArray)
        json.put("orFilters", JSONArray())
        json.put("aggregationFilter", JSONObject.NULL)
        val sortFieldsArray = JSONArray()
        sortFieldsArray.put("+issuerName")
        json.put("sortFields", sortFieldsArray)
        json.put("limit", 50)
        json.put("offset", 0)
        json.put("delimiter", JSONObject.NULL)
        json.put("quoteValues", false)

        Log.d("JSON", json.toString())


        val url2 = "https://services-dynarep.ddwa.finra.org/public/reporting/v2/data/group/FixedIncomeMarket/name/CorporateAndAgencySecurities"
        val request2 = object: JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url2, json,
            { response ->
                // TODO replace this with our calls to make tab2 display bond data
                val jsonObject = response

                Log.d("Response:", "$response")
            },
            { error ->
                Log.e("Error", error.toString())
            })
        {
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["authority"] = "services-dynarep.ddwa.finra.org"
                headers["accept"] = "application/json, text/plain, */*"
                headers["content-type"] = "application/json"
                headers["cookie"] = "XSRF-TOKEN=$cfruid;"
                headers["origin"] = "https://www.finra.org"
                headers["referer"] = "https://www.finra.org/"
                headers["x-xsrf-token"] = cfruid
                headers["host"] = "services-dynarep.ddwa.finra.org"
                Log.d("headers:", headers.toString())
                return headers
            }
        }
        request2.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
            50000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
        )
        queue.add(request2)

    }

finraGetBondInfo("Boeing")
```

Comment: make both request(python/kotlin) against https://www.toptal.com/developers/postbin/ for example and compare what the difference is.

Comment: it won't let me override the headers with `getHeaders()` on that website. So it brings me closer to the issue but does not solve it.